# InDesign GREP help changing mulitple lines format only

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

I am looking for help to make formatting baseball stats for my paper easier. SO far i have been able to use GREP to do a lot of the work for me as changing the lines for every game is tedious. Below is an example from the portion I need to change:

[image]

I want to change everything from the IP line to the last line prior to ROCKIES 10. 
Here is the GREP I have been, but i cant get it to work with everything from point A to point B

\r\r\tIP.*(?=\u\u)

That should grab everything from the double return with tab and IP all the way to the first two Uppercase letters. I have tested it code by code and \r\r\tIP.* grabs the returns and first line needed only. adding the rest gives me no matches. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

GREP is, by default, constrained to a single 'line' in its forward matching operators. 'Line' is GREP terminology here and has nothing to do with lines of text; in InDesign they are actually the *paragraphs*. The construction `.*` will automatically stop testing at the end of the paragraph it is active in (which is the line with the capitals and tabs).

But there is a flag to change this behavior, oddly called the *single line mode*. (The other one in the GREP modifier dropdown menu, "Multi-line mode", does something else!)

Single Line Mode is on by default; you switch it off by preceding your expression with `(?s)`, which makes the `.` match hard returns as well as all regular characters.<sup>1</sup> So use this

```
(?s)\r\r\tIP.*?(?=\u\u)
```

I added an additional `?` after `.*` because without this, it would read your "ROCKIES" line and then *continue* if there is a later line that *also* starts with 2 uppercase characters - GREP is greedy. The construction `.*?` makes it stop directly after the first succesful match.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is a clue to the inner workings of GREP. Usually, `.` matches *all characters except the Hard Return*, which fully explains your current result. Changing the mode of `.` to *also* match hard returns - i.e., "really everything" - makes it ignore the returns and continue testing after a paragraph end.
The Multi-Line Mode does a similar thing for the two codes `^` and `$`.